# Templated class around boost::ptree headache

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm struggling to find out why code with the following snippet will not compile.  There may be something I don't understand about class templates (ie the typedef typename thing) but I don't think that's it in this particular case.

```
template<typename data_type>
class GlobalStore {

private:
    typedef boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<
        std::string,
        data_type,
        std::less<std::string>
    > _StorageTreeType;

    _StorageTreeType _store;

public:
    // snip

    template<typename T>
    const T Get(_StorageTreeType & st, const std::string & name)
    {
        return st.get<T>(name);  //Compilation chokes here
    }
};
```

I have used the exact same setup, though outside of a templated class (but still using an **exactly identical** line to that shown above).  The compiler (GCC/MingW) error is

> expected primary expression before `'>'` token

If I replace `T` with `int` or something on that line it still won't compile ("expected primary expression before `int`").

Any thoughts? Boost::ptree documentation is at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
return st.get<T>(name);
```

to

```
return st.template get<T>(name);
```

See this FAQ for more info: [What is the `->template`, `.template` and `::template` syntax about?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix)

Comment: Excellent, concise and to the point.  Thanks for the link - I tried searching along those lines but would never have found that.